# Parsing CityGML with PyXB

Tags: python, citygml

I'm trying to parse a CityGML file in python in order to generate python objects from the buildings. Optimally the objects would have attributes corresponding to the elements in the GML, more or less like `city.buildingID('123').roof.geom`, which would give me the roof geometry.

I'm aware that specific elements/features can be extracted from CityGML using ElementTree, however I'm looking for a more comprehensive approach, because I need to iteratively access several different parts of each building.

I came accross PyXB, which to my understanding, could help me achieve exactly what I need. It generates python bindings from XSDs, then parses any XML using the corresponding schema to python objects. I generated the bindings using PyXB's provided binding-generator, adapted for CityGML2.0 (https://gist.github.com/balazsdukai/39668a068baf769f64d704e97baa6bbd).

Unfortunately my minimal example does not parse my minimal file. The file contains about 10 buildings, its CityGML2.0, semantically valid and has a non-planar surface according to val3dity.

```
import os
import pyxb
import pyxb.bundles.opengis.citygml.pbase as pbase # http://www.opengis.net/citygml/profiles/base/2.0

path = "loerrach_sub1.gml"

def citygml_read(gml_path):
    """
    Generates python classes from a citygml file.
    """
    gml = open(gml_path).read()
    pyxb.RequireValidWhenParsing(True) # do/not validate gml file when parsing to binding instance
    try:
        citygml_model = pbase.CreateFromDocument(gml, location_base=gml_path)
        return citygml_model
    except pyxb.ValidationError as e:
        print(e.details())

loer_sub1 = citygml_read(path)
```

The problem is that with `pyxb.RequireValidWhenParsing(False)` PyXB raises and exception:

```
pyxb.exceptions_.StructuralBadDocumentError:
{http://www.opengis.net/gml}FeaturePropertyType cannot accept wildcard content <pyxb.utils.saxdom.Element object at 0x7f5d728f1240>
```

The package author says that this is, because wildcards are not allowed by the schema (https://github.com/pabigot/pyxb/issues/53). Now, I manually checked if there are wildcards `any*` in the file but there are none.

Following I tried `pyxb.RequireValidWhenParsing(True)`, but then I get:

```
The containing element {http://www.opengis.net/citygml/2.0}cityObjectMember is defined at cityGMLBase.xsd[47:1].
The containing element type {http://www.opengis.net/gml}FeaturePropertyType is defined at feature.xsd[76:1]
The unrecognized content WallSurface begins at loerrach_sub1.gml[10:0]
The {http://www.opengis.net/gml}FeaturePropertyType automaton is in an accepting state.
The following element and wildcard content would be accepted:
An element {http://www.opengis.net/gml}_Feature per feature.xsd[81:3]
Unable to convert DOM node {http://www.opengis.net/citygml/building/2.0}WallSurface at loerrach_sub1.gml[10:0] to binding
```

So, I don't really know what is going wrong here. It seems like something is missing from the bindings, but I believe I included all CityGML-related XSDs.

Answer (score 1):

You might find the [CityGML2OBJs](https://github.com/tudelft3d/CityGML2OBJs) and [gml2obj](https://github.com/Killermachine/gml2obj) tools helpful.

They are both Python tools parsing buildings meshes from CityGML files.